# Passing Parameters from handleMessage to a button upon a click

Tags: android, multithreading, button

I have defined a button on Android where upon being clicked, I need
to read some data back. The steps in doing so are shown below:

1- OnStart(), I make a call to a thread as follows:

```
mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
mConnectedThread.start();
```

2- The "run" public function of the above thread makes some calculation and then sends the result back to the message handler as shown here:

```
msg_handler.obtainMessage(READ_BUF_HAS_UP_STATUS, num_of_read_bytes, -1).sendToTarget();
```

3- The message handler has been defined as follows in onCreate:

```
       msg_handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                // if received buffer has any data, then process it here:

                case READ_BUF_HAS_UP_STATUS:

                    up_idle_status_byte = readBuf[0];
                    n_bytes = msg.arg1;
                    Log.d(TAG, "....We have received the up status! And it is: "+up_idle_status_byte);

                    break;
            }
        }

        ;
    };
```

4- The "readStatus" button which reads the status from the above thread is defined as follows in "onCreate". As shown below, a call to *mConnectedThread.readStatusReg()* would cause the status to be read back from the thread's "run" procedure which subsequently is handed over to the above message handler:

```
       readStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            mConnectedThread.readStatusReg();
            while (!msg_handler.hasMessages(READ_BUF_HAS_UP_STATUS)) {
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "There is NO message from msg_handler yet");
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(80);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        String msg = "clicked readStatus and an exception occurred when sleeping for some time" + e.getMessage();
                        errorExit("Fatal Error", msg);
                    }
                }
             }
             if (up_idle_status_byte == (byte) 0x01){
                    //do something
             }
             else{
                    //do something else
             }
    });
```

The problem is that "up_idle_status_byte" value which is captured by the message handler, is not seen by this button event [it always ends up in the "else" statement above]. If the message handler is acting in parallel with button activity -- which I suspected so -- I would have imagined that the button handler should be able to eventually see the correct status value. But that is not the case and message handler seems to be operating sequentially. Meaning that regardless of how much I pause in the button handler loop, I never see the path through "*if (up_idle_status_byte == (byte) 0x01)*" being executed. 
And as soon as the button activity exits, the sequential manner of message handler shows the value of up_idle_status_byte to be correctly set to one!! [note that up_idle_status_byte is defined as a global variable]

So why can't I see any parameters created in handleMessage simultaneously available in the button click [sorry if this is such a novice question, but again I am not claiming otherwise!!...]?

Thanks a lot for your input and advice.

Comment: I'm a little confused on the method you're using here.  So all you want to accomplish is some background work and then have it accessible to the UI?  Why do you wait to do the actual work when you hit readStatus?

Comment: I am trying to read the status of a device and that may take sometime. But at any rates, the problem is not the fact that I am waiting on some read data, but I am baffled by why the message handler sets this global "up_idle_status_byte", and yet the button activity (or as you said it UI) cannot detect that.

Comment: It would seem from your code that both the handler and click handler are running on the same thread - therefore being serviced by the same Looper message queue which is why they behaving as you say.  In general I don't know that this is a great architecture for what you're trying to achieve.  You may consider using something like an IntentService to handle the blocking call then a PendingIntent to notify the main Activity thread when it's done.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the response. But anywhere and everywhere that I have seen, it was recommended strongly that both the handler as well as UI to be on the "main thread". So I did not suspect that could cause an issue. You might be right and this might not be a great architecture for what I am trying to do, but I guess I can defy the criticism due to my admission that I am a total novice in the post!! Do you happen to have piece of code that could show me what you were suggesting?

Comment: Well, I wrote a blog post about the pattern here: http://blog.vaporstream.com/blog/2013/07/09/concurrency-patterns-intent-service/ I'm sure you can also find several others.  I've used this pattern for network access but it should also work nicely for blocking device calls - especially if you have more than one request/response message you need to send to it.  If it really is just a single call, the handler method may work but you may need to rethink your threading model - for instance spawn a background thread from the clickhandler that queries the byte.

Comment: I will read your blog carefully, but before I get involved with a major surgery on the code, couple of questions: 1- Don't you really think that the issue that I am describing is odd (and isn't that the way that majority of coders do when they use a thread handler in conjunction with a UI)? 2- And if I need to carry out your suggestion for a background thread, again is there a sample code so I do not fall in another endless pitfall?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem: there is no "button activity" that runs parallel to the message handler. The button's onClick() code is run inside of a message on the main handler, just like your code to read the status.

What you are trying to do here—make a network request *and* receive the result of that request inside the same button listener—is not possible. Each unit of work on the main thread must be small, so you will need to have the button make the request, and then have a separate part do the remaining work when the request finishes (likely inside the message handler).

If you are referring to our book (obligatory plug: [Big Nerd Ranch Guide to Android Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321804333)), I strongly recommend building the example exercises for chapters 26 and 27 according to the instructions and understanding how they work. There's a world of difference between doing that and trying to read and cherry pick for a small piece of understanding.

Comment: I agree.  Doing threading well on Android means gaining a firm understanding of all the underlying mechanisms we are given in the APK.  There is really no substitute for coding up full blown examples and fully learning how the tools are supposed to be used.  Otherwise it is easy to get lost and implement patterns incorrectly.

Comment: Bill thanks for your response (and BTW that is a great book). It is good to know why my method does not work, but the issue I am now facing is that different buttons in my program preform different reads of data from different sections of memory. The response to these reads will be different depending on WHO initiated the read. So if my method does not work, then whether I use "a separate part", or "inside the message handler", these methods need to somehow  find out WHO initiated the read and then take the appropriate action.

Comment: when you say WHO here do you mean the button that kicked off the call?  So each button results in a different read from the device correct?

Comment: That is correct. Each button initiates a different read, and upon receiving the read result back, it has to respond to it differently... and that is the core of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I really think you should consider the following architecture for this app.
There are three main steps:

1. When a button is clicked, send a (button specific) signal to an IntentService
2. The IntentService performs the appropriate action depending on the OPCODE
3. After the IntentService finishes work, it returns the result back to the calling Activity

If you use PendingIntents, after the service does it's work you will get a callback in your Activity using onActivityResult.  In onActivityResult, you will know which result it is because when you launched the Service from the button you sent a unique int value to identify the caller.  Therefore, you can handle the return for each result you get in a different way depending on who the caller was.

As far as code goes, again I refer you to http://blog.vaporstream.com/blog/2013/07/09/concurrency-patterns-intent-service/